# How to use (install) dblink in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I am used to Oracle and to create a dblink in my schema and then access to a remote database like this: `mytable@myremotedb`, is there anyway do to the same with PostgreSQL?

Right now I am using dblink like this:

```
SELECT logindate FROM dblink('host=dev.toto.com
                              user=toto
                              password=isok
                              dbname=totofamily', 'SELECT logindate FROM loginlog');
```

When I execute this command I get the following error:

> HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Does anybody have an idea ? Do we have to "activate" dblinks or do something before using them?

Is there something to do on the remote database we are going to query? Do we have to activate dblink too? I keep having a `could not establish connection`. This is the line is type:

```
SELECT dblink_connect_u('host=x.x.x.x dbname=mydb user=root port=5432');
```

IP Address is correct and Postgres is running on the remote server. Any idea?

Answer (score 145):

Since **PostgreSQL 9.1**, installation of additional modules is simple. [Registered extensions like `dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) can be installed with [`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Installs into your default schema, which is `public` by default. Make sure your `search_path` is set properly before you run the command. The schema must be visible to all roles who have to work with it. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Alternatively, you can install to any schema of your choice with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink SCHEMA extensions;
```

See:

- [Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146433/best-way-to-install-hstore-on-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgres-database/19146824#19146824)

Run once per database. Or run it in the standard system database `template1` to add it to *every* newly created DB automatically. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html)

You need to have the files providing the module installed on the server first. For Debian and derivatives this would be the package [`postgresql-contrib-9.1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101055/939860) - for PostgreSQL 9.1, obviously. Since Postgres 10, there is just a `postgresql-contrib` metapackage.

Comment: Nothing is so simple with PostgreSQL... Error "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/dblink.control": File ou directory not found... There are a simple command to fix it?

Comment: ... Idem in another server with modern pg9.3 (at Debian). SQL message is "ERROR:  could not open extension control file '/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/dblink.control': No such file or directory"

Comment: @PeterKrauss: Did you install the contrib package as advised? pg 9.3 is not in the current stable release (wheezy). You get it from the **[PostgreSQL Apt Repository](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/)**.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips and clues (!), I will succeed ... But, again, I am confirming that PostgreSQL never will be plug-and-play... If something "has been simplified", was slow and need more, and the rest of the world evolved faster.

Comment: Why doesn't postgres have this enabled by default? Coming from SQL Server I was often doing cross database queries, this seems like a common requirement?

Answer (score 33):

I am using DBLINK to connect internal database for cross database queries.

**[Reference taken from this article.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/05/postgresql-cross-database-queries-using/)**

**Install DbLink extension.**

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

**Verify DbLink:**

```
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname, pg_proc.proname 
FROM pg_proc, pg_namespace 
WHERE pg_proc.pronamespace=pg_namespace.oid 
   AND pg_proc.proname LIKE '%dblink%';
```

**Test connection of database:**

```
SELECT dblink_connect('host=localhost user=postgres password=enjoy dbname=postgres');
```

Answer (score 12):

On linux, find dblink.sql, then execute in the postgresql console something like this to create all required functions:

```
\i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/dblink.sql
```

you might need to install the contrib packages: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib`

Comment: With package `postgres-contrib-9.3`, `dblink.sql` is now `dblink--1.1.sql`.

Comment: Mine was found into `/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/`. PostgreSQL 9.5, running on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

Installing modules usually requires you to run an sql script that is included with the database installation.

Assuming linux-like OS

```
find / -name dblink.sql
```

Verify the location and run it

Answer (score 2):

It can be added by using:

```
$psql -d databaseName -c "CREATE EXTENSION dblink"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# or even faster copy paste answer if you have sudo on the host 
sudo su - postgres  -c "psql template1 -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"dblink\";'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall ask additionally, where to install `dblink`?

On most cases recommended location where to install common Postgers extensions is `pg_catalog` schema. If you install extensions in pg_catalog, then all related functions are available within any schema. If you install extension in `public`, then inside another schema, you have to define also schema.

For example, if dblink is installed in `public`, then within schema `myschema`, you **have to** define `public` schema.

```
SELECT public.dblink_get_connections();
```

For example, if dblink is installed in `pg_catalog`, then within scheme `myschema`, you **do not have** to define `public` schema:

```
SELECT dblink_get_connections();
```

All functions in schema `pg_catalog` are appended to other schemas automatically.

To install `dblink` in `pg_catalog`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
```