# Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql, unaccent

I am trying to configure PostgreSQL to use fulltext search in my rails app as mentioned in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql).

I am using a fresh `Ubuntu 12.04` server running `PostgreSQL 9.1.5` installed using `apt-get` with the `ppa:pitti/postgresql` with `precise`.

I get the following error when trying to run the migration and when I try the same command in the psql console with the peer postgres user:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

> ERROR:  could not open extension  control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/unaccent.control":
>   No such file or directory

In my local box running `Ubuntu 10.04 desktop` I use the same repository (`natty`) and it works well.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to install the package **`postgresql-contrib-9.1`** in your system first. (Adapt to your version number! Here is the [currently available list of packages.](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=postgresql-contrib)) That's the case under **Debian**, **Ubuntu** & friends anyway. Using a system user with the necessary privileges:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

If your currently logged in user does not have the necessary privileges (but `sudo` rights):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

Quoting the [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/):

> If the version included in your version of Debian is not the one you
>   want, you can use the PostgreSQL Apt Repository.

There are [basic install instructions on the Postgres website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) for each available OS.

For accent-insensitive indices using `unaccent` consider this related question:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations)

Comment: Fedora Users: ```yum install postgresql-contrib```

Comment: @AlterLagos: You need `sudo`, if your currently logged in user does not have the necessary privileges (but `sudo` rights).

Comment: Yep, but that was not the big change. For you worked with `postgresql-contrib-9.1` but that package was not available for me, instead I use `postgresql-contrib` and worked like a charm. I guess it should be because I'm using the official repo as source `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/`

Comment: this command works for me  sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3

Answer (score 8):

On CentOS:

```
sudo yum install postgres*contrib
```

Comment: I've just tried that on Centos 6.4 and got this message: "No package postgres*contrib available".