# SORT in PostgreSQL: strings with parenthesis

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have just found out something very curious in PostgreSQL. Suppose we have a column "name" with values like

```
bbb
(ccc)
aaa
(eee)
ddd
```

If I do a SELECT (...) ORDER BY name ASC, the result is

```
aaa
bbb
(ccc)
ddd
(eee)
```

That was very clever, but what I had previously in MySQL (and what I really want now) is

```
(ccc)
(eee)
aaa
bbb
ddd
```

Any idea why that happens and how can I fix it?

**Edit**: as mentioned in the comments, it looks like the guilty lies on the en_US.UTF-8 collation. But I need it to correctly sort strings with latin characters. So is there any regex or an alternative collation to solve the problem?

Comment: It seems to be related to the environment. On http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0876/3 this works the same way as you see it. If I do that in psql on my computer I get the `(ccc)` as the first row. Maybe some collation setting?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is related to collation or something. My environment uses C and doesn't have this problem; the production server uses en_US.UTF-8 and does have the problem. But I need some good collation to properly handle latin characters, so what do I do?

Comment: If you want to be independent of the collation it's probably better to order by a "clean" version of the column. Something like `order by regexp_replace(the_column, '[^a-zA-Z]', '')`

Comment: Many parts of the website use the regular sort (with en_US.UTF-8 collation), and only one have that parenthesis problem. So it would be nice to find a solution (perhaps with a regex) to address this case in particular.

Comment: The solution I showed you *does* use a regex.

Comment: Indeed, but it needs some adaptation. I will try something similar to replace the parenthesis for some character that comes before "a". I will post the answer here if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the same question. One of its solutions works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are prefer collation `C`, why not explicitly use it in the order statement?

```
SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY (name COLLATE "C");
```

Works on my system.

Or if in specific, you'd like to ignore the difference between the same letter with different accents (like collation `en-US` etc), but NOT ignore brackets (like collation `C`), you can strip accents using `unaccent()` and then keep using `C`. (Even though this might give you random orders within the same letter.)

```
SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY (unaccent(name) COLLATE "C");
```

See how to get `unaccent()` working if (not already) here:
[Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql)

Another solution, if your problem is *exactly* with an opening bracket on the first character, is the following:

```
SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY (NOT substring(name from 1 for 1)='(', name);
```

If this is not sufficient, I suggest to rethink *why* not ignoring brackets is so important for you and if you could include that information on another column etc.

Comment: If that really is the solution, then changing the column to always use that collation is probably the easiest solution (as all existing queries will automatically apply that collation)

Comment: True, and indeed the fact that the dev and prod environments use different collations shows that something is wrong with propagating schema changes from dev to prod.

Comment: Well, that solution will give me problems with latin accented characters.

Comment: You wrote earlier that "My environment uses C and doesn't have this problem" so now I am confused. Maybe you'll need to define your own collation :) Can you be more specific with what the "problems" are (example)?

Comment: I have updated my answer stripping off accents or catching the opening bracket on the first character, how about now? -- If this is not sufficient, then can you explain in more detail why you can't ignore brackets? What do they mean, are they really only brackets?