# PostgreSQL import not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, import, sql-import-wizard

I have been trying to import a postgres dump (with `psql dbname < dump.sql` and its variants, specifying hostname and username and so on), but I have been unsuccessful with it so far.

I am new to Postgres, so I may have been missing the obvious here. Based on the output of importing commands, the extension plpgsql probably doesn't exist. Am I expected to set up the plpgsql extension before I import?

Here are the first few lines of the output:

```
SET
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "lock_timeout"
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
ERROR:  extension "hstore" does not exist
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  relation "active_admin_comments" already exists
ERROR:  role "finalstep" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "active_admin_comments_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  role "finalstep" does not exist
ALTER SEQUENCE
ERROR:  relation "admin_users" already exists
ERROR:  role "finalstep" does not exist
```

Later down the road, it looks like it's trying to execute some of the content as sql queries (the content contains mathml tags):

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "</"
LINE 1: </mo> <msqrt>
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "&"
LINE 1: &nbsp;
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "</"
LINE 1: </mi> <mi>&alpha;
```

Any pointers? My Postgres version is 9.1 (it was 9.3 initially, but I downgraded it to 9.1 after seeing the error messages).

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say without the file itself. Some pointers:

- I would stick with version **9.3** if at all possible. Many improvements over 9.1, and you will have more time before you need to upgrade again.
  Also, the first error message indicates you *need* Postgres 9.3 anyway, since the GUC (configuration setting) [`lock_timeout` was introduced with Postgres 9.3.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT)
- Use [`psql` with the **`-f`** switch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3) to get more detailed error messages:

  ```
  psql dbname -f dump.sql
  ```

  (And there is no `-` in front of `dbname`: <strike>`-dbname`</strike>, that's just a typo, I assume?)
- Language **`plpgsql`** shouldn't  be a problem if your installation isn't broken. 
  [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-overview.html)

  > In PostgreSQL 9.0 and later, PL/pgSQL is installed by default.
- These error messages indicate problems reading files from your contrib package at the OS level.

  > ```
  > ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
  > ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
  > ERROR:  extension "hstore" does not exist
  > ```

  - You need the optional package `postgresql-contrib-9.1` (or `postgresql-contrib-9.3` respectively) installed for additional modules like `hstore`. Details in this related answer:
    [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql/12101055#12101055)
  - The files must be accessible to the system user that started Postgres, typically `postgres` (the OS user). I.e., when typing `whoami` in the shell, the answer should be `postgres`.
  - Also, you must be executing the bash command as superuser, typically as `postgres` (the DB user). Typically, if you don't specify a user name, and `IDENT` or `PEER` authentication is enabled (default), then the DB user matching the OS user is used automatically. Details in this related answer:
    [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Comment: Thanks for the help, fixed the -dbname typo. Switched to 9.3, which took care of some of the problems. Installed postgres-contrib-9.3, but problems still persist. I am trying a few things, and I'll come back here to post my progress.