# Missing hstore extension

Tags: postgresql, hstore, postgresql-extensions

I am running PostgreSQL 9.5.3 Fedora Linux, and I tried to create the "hstore" extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
```

But I got this error:

> could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory

How can I install hstore?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? How did you install Postgres? On most Linux systems you need to install the -contrib package manually.

Comment: I am on fedora,how can I check if it is installed?

Answer (score 15):

The package providing additional modules must be installed in your system.

For Fedora (as privileged system user):

```
yum install postgresql-contrib
```

Or (for plain users):

```
sudo yum install postgresql-contrib
```

For Debian & friends, see:

- [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql/12101055#12101055)

Comment: use postgresql11-contrib if you want to install for postgres11