# I'm using postgres database. I want to create dblink with mysql database. What should I do?

Tags: postgresql

```
sudo PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1 clean


sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib/libjvm.so


CREATE EXTENSION jdbc_fdw;

– MySQL JDBC

sudo -u postgres psql postgres;

CREATE SERVER jdbc_mysql FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER jdbc_fdw OPTIONS(
    drivername 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
    url 'jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/bookshoputem',
    querytimeout '15',
    jarfile '/home/user2010/Documents/DBLINK/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar',
    maxheapsize '600'
    );


CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER jdbc_mysql OPTIONS(username 'root',password 'abc123');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE Inventory_mysql
(int_inventoryid VARCHAR(10) ,
int_stockin int ,
int_stockout int ,
int_balancequantity int ,
int_reorderlevel int ,
bk_isbn VARCHAR(20)) 
SERVER jdbc_mysql
OPTIONS (table 'Inventory');
----------------------
```

While I run this command, I just get data from mysql, but it doesn't delete or update from mysql database. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe your MySQL credentials only allow read-only data access?

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-foreign-data.html) says:

```
Currently, foreign tables are read-only. 
This limitation may be fixed in a future release.
```

Try to use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html). 
Some helpful information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql).