# How do i use dblink in Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql-9.2, dblink

We have recenctly upgraded our Postgres DB from 9.0 to 9.2 but we are facing challenges installing & using dblink on this DB Engine. Please help and advice on how to install and use dblink on Postgres 9.2.

Comment: see duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql