# Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, hstore, postgresql-extensions

I'm working on a project that needs to use `hstore` on multiple schemas.
The 'public' schema, where the `hstore` extension was being installed isn't available everywhere, because my scope doesn't lookup at 'public'. On some tryouts, I've created the extension on a schema called 'hstore' and used the schema on every available scope (search path) used.

Based on this, I've some questions:

- Is it ok to create a schema just for the extension? Or is it better to create the extension on every single schema (like, `customer_1`, `customer_2`, and so on...)?
- Does the creation of the extension in a separate schema affect where the data is stored? I'm using multiple schemas to make it easier to backup/restore, and really don't want pg to store all my `hstore` data in a hidden table (like `pg_large_objects` for blobs) on a single schema.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not allowed to install extensions multiple times per database. Quoting [the manual on `CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html):

> Remember that the extension itself is not considered to be within any
> schema: extensions have unqualified names that must be unique
> database-wide. But objects belonging to the extension can be within schemas.

If you don't want to include `public` in your [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777), install "public" extensions into a dedicated schema (example: `extensions`). I would use a single schema for all of them, not a separate schema for each extension. [There are quite a few of them.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html)
[`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) offers an option to install to an existing schema of your choice:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore SCHEMA extensions;
```

And make sure the schema is included in the `search_path` of users who might want to make use of it.

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Data storage is not affected at all by the schema the extension resides in.

Comment: The `extensions` schema would need to be added to search_path, correct?

Comment: @Qcom: Correct. And the sequence of schemas in the search_path is relevant, too. *Or* you have to schema-qualify all objects you want to reference - including operators! Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975599/how-to-use-operator-from-the-extension-pg-trgm/22975642#22975642

Comment: Are there any obvious benefits other than clarity in installing extensions in a dedicated schema rather than using public?

Comment: @Qcom: `public` is just another schema. The only thing special about it, is that it's installed by default and the default search_path uses it. A dedicated schema for extensions is mainly for clarity, easier management, easier handling of backups ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install extension hstore on all schemas

```
create extension hstore schema pg_catalog;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store non-core things in `pg_catalog`