# How to use % operator from the extension pg_trgm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, search-path

I have my `pg_trgm` module installed.

```
pg_trgm | 1.0     | extensions | text similarity measurement and index ...
```

The schema set is `extensions`. To use it I have to run something like this select:

```
extensions.similarity('hello','hallo');
```

I'm trying to run a statement using the `%` operator and got the following message.

```
mydb=# select * from rssdata where description % 'Brazil';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying % unknown
LINE 1: select * from rssdata where description % 'Brazil';
                                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What is necessary to run `%` or `<->` operators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably the problem is with the [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) setting. Run:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Is the schema where you installed [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) included? If not, include it.

Or, if you have the necessary privileges, you can [change the schema of an extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterextension.html) with:

```
ALTER EXTENSION pg_trgm SET SCHEMA public;  -- or the schema you want
```

Alternatively, you can schema-qualify functions - and even operators using the [`OPERATOR()` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE):

```
SELECT * FROM rssdata WHERE extensions.similarity(description, 'Brazil') > .8;
SELECT * FROM rssdata WHERE description OPERATOR(extensions.%) 'Brazil';
```

Removes dependency on the `search_path`. But it's tedious.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to pg_catalog. 
ALTER EXTENSION pg_trgm SET SCHEMA pg_catalog; Seems that it works.

Comment: @user3491961: But `pg_catalog` is a bad idea. This should be reserved for system objects. Install extensions to the `public` schema or to a dedicated `extension` schema and be sure to include the schema in the search_path. Do *not* abuse `pg_catalog` for that!

Comment: Thanks. Started yesterday learning Postgresql. Thanks for this.

Comment: create extentions within the schema: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gin WITH SCHEMA extensions;` `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA extensions;` should work after this