# Cannot add hstore column to multitenant rails 4 applicaiton (postgres schema based)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I'm trying to add hstore to my application. However i get an error telling me that hstore does not exists.

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "people" ADD COLUMN "custom_fields" hstore
```

This is my migration:

```
class AddCustomFieldsToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :people, :custom_fields, :hstore
  end

  def down
    remove_column :people, :custom_fields
  end
end
```

Acording to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146433/best-way-to-install-hstore-on-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgres-database) i do not have to create the hstore extention on every schema but only add it to for example the public schema.

Is there anything i need to do other that adding the postgres extension to get hstore to work?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Try: \c <DB_NAME>;
create extension hstore;

Comment: I have already added hstore. so i get ERROR:  'extension "hstore" already exists' :-/

Comment: What is your version PostgreSQL && Rails ?

Comment: Postgres version 9.3 and Rails 4.0.2

Comment: Using the Postgres app for mac osx

Comment: What the result of the SELECT 'a=>1'::hstore; in psql ?

Comment: There is no response. imagesite_development=# SELECT 'a=>1'::hstore
imagesite_development-#

Comment: Hmm, try this: drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore; And again: SELECT 'a=>1'::hstore;

Comment: I didn't want to resett my development database, so i tried running 'DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS hstore;' and then add it again with 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;' i then got this working all inside psql. however Rails is still not allowing me to add hstore columns using migrations.

Comment: I understand that you do not have migration works, but first want to make sure that the extension works in the database itself. For example in my DB: SELECT 'a=>1'::hstore; Result:
  hstore  
----------
 "a"=>"1"
(1 row)

Comment: Yes. this works in my database: DB: SELECT 'a=>1'::hstore; Result: hstore ---------- "a"=>"1"

Comment: Try then now: ALTER DATABASE <mydb> SET search_path = public, hstore; and run migration again.

Comment: Still getting the same error :-/

Comment: well, let's try the other side, in migration insert: enable_extension "hstore" above add_column, run migration, and show results :)

Comment: Still the same error :-/, can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using the `apartment` gem?

Comment: No, i followed this railscast episode when i created the multitenancy: http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql

Comment: If you are using any Configuration management system like Chef or Puppet, add hstore to template1 database in PostgreSQL. That avoids from having a migration to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a migration with this and rake:

```
class AddHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def up
    enable_extension :hstore
  end

  def down
    disable_extension :hstore
  end
end
```

Since you will have a migration pending already, use    rake db:migrate:up     VERSION=