# Additional module citext is installed, but type "citext" not found?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, search-path, postgresql-extensions

I'm trying to run an inline query on my database - which has the `citext` extension installed (using `CREATE EXTENSION`) - and yet the executed query keeps throwing this error when calling a function:

> ```
> type "citext" does not exist
> ```

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  _id INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM "dbo"."MyFunction"(_id, 'some value'::citext);
END;
$$;
```

If I omit the `::citext` cast, it says:

> ```
> function dbo.MyFunction(integer, unknown) does not exist.
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

The `citext` extension is added, is part of the schema and works with other queries. This keeps coming up randomly - what causes it?

EDIT:
The installed extensions:

```
extname   | nspname
----------+-----------
plpgsql   | pg_catalog
citext    | public
uuid-ossp | public
```

Search path:

```
show search_path;
search_path
-----------
dbo
```

Comment: `citext ...  is part of the schema` - part of which schema? Run: `SELECT e.extname, n.nspname FROM pg_extension e JOIN  pg_namespace n ON n.oid = e.extnamespace;` And what do you get for `show search_path`?

Comment: updated question to reflect that information. Interesting to note that I also seem to have this problem trying to use uuid_generate_v4() in an inline query.

Comment: oh man.. this might be specific to DataGrip 2016 and the way it initiates connections. I tried the same query with pgAdmin and the search_path contains the extensions, whereas it does not in DataGrip.

Comment: Unrelated but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: So it is as suspected. I added some more pointers to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, the extension schema is missing from the **`search_path`**. Read up on how to set the schema search path in this related answer:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

It seems like your client sets  `search_path = dbo` on connection, which seems to be misconfigured. `dbo` is something we see a lot for SQL Server (used to be the default schema here or still is?), very untypical for Postgres. Not sure how you got there.

- [Why do table names in SQL Server start with "dbo"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo)

One alternative would be to install extensions into the `dbo` schema as well:

- [Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146433/best-way-to-install-hstore-on-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgres-database/19146824#19146824)

You can even [move (most) extensions to a different schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterextension.html):

```
ALTER EXTENSION citext SET SCHEMA dbo;
```

But I would advice to install extensions to a dedicated schema and include it in the `search_path`.

Leave `plpgsql` alone in any case. It's installed by default and should  should stay in `pg_catalog`.

One way or another, clean up the mess with varying `search_path` settings.

---

As for the second question: that's guided by the rules of [Function Type Resolution](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html). The call cannot be resolved, because `citext` does not have an implicit cast to `text`.

Related

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)