# Using Postgis extension installed in different Postgres Schema

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm having a go at setting up my first Postgres database, but am getting quite confused about why I'm having issues with enabling Postgis in one schema and then using it in another.

I'm using Google Cloud SQL with Postgres v12.
I'm connecting via the Cloud SQL proxy, and have connected to the server via both pgAdmin4 and a Jupyter Notebook (SQLAlchemy).

My goal is to write a shapefile full of points into a table on the database via geopandas.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146824/9837690) I'm trying to install postgis into a separate schema, while creating a couple more different schemas where my data will actually go.
I'm opening the shapefile in geopandas, and then using .to_postgis() to try and save the shapefile contents into a new table in one of my data schemas. This always fails.

However, if I try to write the geodataframe into the extensions schema, it works just fine. This makes me think that there's something wrong with the search_path, but no idea what.
I'm setting the search path as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790972/9837690).
I've tried a range ways to setup the search_path, but I think there's something lacking in my fundamental understanding of what it does and how it works.

Here's the workflow:

- (create the postgres server on Google Cloud SQL)
- (get the proxy up and running)
- (connect to pgAdmin)
- (create a database in pgAdmin called "mydb", equivalent to "CREATE DATABASE mydb")
- (open Query Tool in pgAdmin)

SQL:

```
CREATE SCHEMA extensions;
CREATE SCHEMA geodata;
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path = geodata,extensions,public;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA extensions;
```

And then in the jupyter notebook:

```
# imports
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import geopandas as gpd

# connect to database
dbschema = 'geodata' # note, if I change this to 'extensions' it works
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:<password>@localhost:5432/mydb', connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

# Open shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\path\to\shapefile.shp")

# Attempt to write shapefile to postgis
gdf.to_postgis(name = 'geotable', con = engine)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
UndefinedObject                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1275                 if not evt_handled:
-> 1276                     self.dialect.do_execute(
   1277                         cursor, statement, parameters, context

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 

UndefinedObject: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 7:  geometry geometry(POINT,28354)
                  ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a0dc69a1128e> in <module>
      1 from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
----> 2 gdf.to_postgis(name = 'vines', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_postgis(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   1095         >>> gdf.to_postgis("my_table", engine)
   1096         """
-> 1097         geopandas.io.sql._write_postgis(
   1098             self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype
   1099         )

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\sql.py in _write_postgis(gdf, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    390     with con.begin() as connection:
    391 
--> 392         gdf.to_sql(
    393             name,
    394             connection,

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2651         from pandas.io import sql
   2652 
-> 2653         sql.to_sql(
   2654             self,
   2655             name,

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
    510         )
    511 
--> 512     pandas_sql.to_sql(
    513         frame,
    514         name,

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method)
   1314             dtype=dtype,
   1315         )
-> 1316         table.create()
   1317         table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
   1318         if not name.isdigit() and not name.islower():

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in create(self)
    653                 raise ValueError(f"'{self.if_exists}' is not valid for if_exists")
    654         else:
--> 655             self._execute_create()
    656 
    657     def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in _execute_create(self)
    639         # Inserting table into database, add to MetaData object
    640         self.table = self.table.tometadata(self.pd_sql.meta)
--> 641         self.table.create()
    642 
    643     def create(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in create(self, bind, checkfirst)
    925         if bind is None:
    926             bind = _bind_or_error(self)
--> 927         bind._run_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)
    928 
    929     def drop(self, bind=None, checkfirst=False):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _run_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
   1654 
   1655     def _run_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs):
-> 1656         visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
   1657 
   1658 

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py in traverse_single(self, obj, **kw)
    143             meth = getattr(v, "visit_%s" % obj.__visit_name__, None)
    144             if meth:
--> 145                 return meth(obj, **kw)
    146 
    147     def iterate(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py in visit_table(self, table, create_ok, include_foreign_key_constraints, _is_metadata_operation)
    825             include_foreign_key_constraints = None
    826 
--> 827         self.connection.execute(
    828             # fmt: off
    829             CreateTable(

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
   1009             )
   1010         else:
-> 1011             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
   1012 
   1013     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
     70 
     71     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
---> 72         return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
     73 
     74     def execute(self, bind=None, target=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_ddl(self, ddl, multiparams, params)
   1066             else None,
   1067         )
-> 1068         ret = self._execute_context(
   1069             dialect,
   1070             dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_ddl,

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1314 
   1315         except BaseException as e:
-> 1316             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
   1317                 e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1318             )

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1508                 util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   1509             elif should_wrap:
-> 1510                 util.raise_(
   1511                     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   1512                 )

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    180 
    181         try:
--> 182             raise exception
    183         finally:
    184             # credit to

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1274                             break
   1275                 if not evt_handled:
-> 1276                     self.dialect.do_execute(
   1277                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1278                     )

~\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    591 
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 
    595     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 7:  geometry geometry(POINT,28354)
                  ^

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE geotable (
    id BIGINT, 
    geometry geometry(POINT,28354)
)

]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are explicitly setting `search_path` when you connect to PostgreSQL. That overrides the value set with `ALTER DATABASE`.

You have two options:

- Set the `search_path` correctly:

  ```
  dbschema = 'geodata,extensions,public'
  ```
- Leave the default setting by *not* setting the `options` parameter in `create_engine`.

Since you have taken the pain to set up a good default value, I'd go with the second option.

I personally use the `public` schema for extensions (after revoking the `CREATE` privilege from `PUBLIC`), but you might opt for dropping the schema altogether.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,
Thanks for that. It makes a bit more sense now.
I didn't realise that setting dbschema in python was overriding the database's search_path.

This might be separate question, but when I change the dbschema value as described, how do I then specify which schema the new table will be created in? I tried "geodata.geotable" but got an error: "UndefinedTable: relation "geodata.geotable" does not exist"

Comment: An unqualified table will be created in the first existing schema on the `search_path`. A qualified table will be created in the schema you specify. The error message you got can obviously *not* come from a `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I tried it without the dbschema variable in the python but couldn't get "geodata.geotable" to work. In the end I used the dbschema variable ensuring the geodata schema was first on the list and so didn't need to use the schema.table naming.
Looks like I'll have to use multiple engine objects (each with different dbschema variables), one for each schema I'll be writing to.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should work fine without explicitly setting the schema. Try without and build a `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path'` into your code. See what `soutce` says where the setting comes from.