# How to use dblink_connect and dblink_connect_u

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, dblink

I have two databases in Postgres and want to access the data from one database to other database tables. I tried the following:

```
dblink_connect('myconn','hostaddr=10.10.30.53 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres')
```

and

```
dblink_connect_u('myconn','hostaddr=10.10.30.53 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres')
```

This results in a syntax error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "dblink_connect"
>   LINE 1: dblink_connect('myconn','hostaddr=10.10.30.53 dbname=postgre... ^
>   ********** Error ********** ERROR: syntax error at or near "dblink_connect" SQL state:

Do I need to change anything in `pg.hba.conf` file?

Can anybody give me the steps with an example?

Comment: What was the syntax error?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "dblink_connect"
LINE 1: dblink_connect('myconn','hostaddr=10.10.30.53 dbname=postgre...
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "dblink_connect"
SQL state: 42601

Answer (score 4):

A syntax error indicates that the statement itself causes problems. Changing `pg_hba.conf` will not solve this. Your statement looks ok - except for the missing `SELECT` (or possibly `PERFORM` in a plpgsql function):

```
SELECT dblink_connect('myconn'
       ,'hostaddr=10.10.30.53 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres')
```

It's a plain SQL `SELECT` statement.
If that's not it, are you sure you have [installed the additional module dblink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961) and your [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) includes the schema you installed it to?