# "UndefinedFunction: function unaccent_schema.unaccent(unknown, text) does not exist" while run any restored database in odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo, unaccent

I am able to run local database, but in the case of restored database I get below error:

```
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb.QWebException: Error while render the template
UndefinedFunction: function unaccent_schema.unaccent(unknown, text) does not exist
LINE 2:                 SELECT unaccent_schema.unaccent('unaccent_sc...
                               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  
                SELECT unaccent_schema.unaccent('unaccent_schema.unaccent', $1)
                
CONTEXT:  SQL function "unaccent" during inlining

Template: web.frontend_layout
```

I have created the extension unaccent in my postgres but it's not working.
I have executed many other commands but no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

The addition module [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) needs to be installed once per database. Not "in my postgres", in particular not in the default maintenance database called "postgres", but **in the actual database you are working with**:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Related:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)
- [How to use (install) dblink in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961)

Basics about Database clusters and databases in the manual chapter [**"Managing Databases"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/managing-databases.html).