# Add new column without table lock?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, locking, thinking-sphinx

In my project having 23 million records and around 6 fields has been indexed of that table.

Earlier I tested to add delta column for Thinking Sphinx search but it turns in holding the whole database lock for an hour. Afterwards when the file is added and I try to rebuild indexes this is the query that holds the database lock for around 4 hours:

```
"update user_messages set delta = false where delta = true"
```

Well for making the server up I created a new database from db dump and promote it as database so server can be turned live.

Now what I am looking is that adding delta column in my table with out table lock is it possible? And once the column `delta` is added then why is the above query executed when I run the index rebuild command and why does it block the server for so long?

PS.: I am on Heroku and using Postgres with ika db model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Postgres 11 or later

Since Postgres 11, only volatile default values still require a table rewrite. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES)

> Adding a column with a **volatile** `DEFAULT` or changing the type of an existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten.

Bold emphasis mine. `false` is immutable. So just add the column with `DEFAULT false`. Super fast, job done:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD column delta boolean DEFAULT false;
```

#### Postgres 10 or older, or for volatile `DEFAULT`

Adding a new column *without* `DEFAULT` or `DEFAULT NULL` will not normally force a table rewrite and is very cheap. Only writing actual values to it creates new rows. But, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES)

> Adding a column with a `DEFAULT` clause or changing the type of an
>   existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten.

`UPDATE` in PostgreSQL writes a new version of the row. Your question does not provide all the information, but that probably means writing millions of new rows.

While doing the `UPDATE` in  place, if a major portion of the table is affected and you are free to lock the table exclusively, remove all indexes before doing the mass `UPDATE` and recreate them afterwards. It's faster this way. [Related advice in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html)

If your data model and available disk space allow for it, **`CREATE`** a new table in the background and then, in one transaction: `DROP` the old table, and **`RENAME`** the new one. Related:

- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52531/3684)

While creating the new table in the background: Apply all changes to the same row at once. Repeated updates create new row versions and leave dead tuples behind.

**If** you cannot remove the original table because of constraints, another fast way is to build a temporary table, **`TRUNCATE`** the original one and mass **`INSERT`** the new rows - sorted, if that helps performance. All in one transaction. Something like this:

```
BEGIN

SET temp_buffers = 1000MB;  -- or whatever you can spare temporarily

-- write-lock table here to prevent concurrent writes - if needed
LOCK TABLE tbl IN SHARE MODE;    

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT *, false AS delta
FROM   tbl;                -- copy existing rows plus new value
-- ORDER BY ???            -- opportune moment to cluster rows

-- DROP all indexes here

TRUNCATE tbl;              -- empty table - truncate is super fast

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD column delta boolean DEFAULT FALSE; -- NOT NULL?

INSERT INTO tbl
TABLE tmp;                 -- insert back surviving rows.

-- recreate all indexes here

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Will the rows inserted in the time the time gap between `INSERT SELECT` and `TRUNCATE` be lost?

Comment: @origaminal: They would have been lost with the code before I updated just now. (There has always been the link to the related question with details for table locks.) Consider the updated version. Most importantly, though, consider the added news for Postgres 11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another table with the one column, there won't be any such long locks. Of course there should be another column, a foreign key to the first column.

For the indexes, you could use "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY", it doesn't use too heavy locks on this table http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html.