# Insert data into remote DB tables from multiple databases through trigger or replication or foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, database-replication

I need some advice about the following scenario.

I have multiple embedded systems supporting PostgreSQL database running at different places and we have a server running on CentOS at our premises.

Each system is running at remote location and has multiple tables inside its database. These tables have the same names as the server's table names, but each system has different table name than the other systems, e.g.:

system 1 has tables:

- `sys1_table1`
- `sys1_table2`

system 2 has tables

- `sys2_table1`
- `sys2_table2`

I want to update the tables `sys1_table1`, `sys1_table2`, `sys2_table1` and `sys2_table2` on the server on every insert done on system 1 and system 2.

One solution is to write a trigger on each table, which will run on every insert of both systems' tables and insert the same data on the server's tables. This trigger will also delete the records in the systems after inserting the data into server. The problem with this solution is that if the connection with the server is not established due to network issue than that trigger will not execute or the insert will be wasted. I have checked the following solution for this
[Trigger to insert rows in remote database after deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011656/trigger-to-insert-rows-in-remote-database-after-deletion)

The second solution is to replicate tables from system 1 and system 2 to the server's tables. The problem with replication will be that if we delete data from the systems, it'll also delete the records on the server. I could add the alternative trigger on the server's tables which will update on the duplicate table, hence the replicated table can get empty and it'll not effect the data, but it'll make a long tables list if we have more than 200 systems.

The third solution is to write a foreign table using postgres_fdw or dblink and update the data inside the server's tables, but will this effect the data inside the server when we delete the data inside the system's table, right? And what will happen if there is no connectivity with the server?

The forth solution is to write an application in python inside each system which will make a connection to server's database and write the data in real time and if there is no connectivity to the server than it will store the data inside the `sys1.table1` or `sys2.table2` or whatever the table the data belongs and after the re-connect, the code will send the tables data into server's tables.

Which option will be best according to this scenario? I like the trigger solution best, but is there any way to avoid the data loss in case of dis-connectivity from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the fourth solution, or perhaps with the third, as long as it is triggered from outside the database. That way you can easily survive connection loss.

The first solution with triggers has the problems you already detected. It is also a bad idea to start potentially long operations, like data replication across a network of uncertain quality, inside a database transaction. Long transactions mean long locks and inefficient autovacuum.

The second solution may actually also be an option if you you have a recent PostgreSQL versions that supports [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). You can use a [publication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpublication.html) `WITH (publish = 'insert,update')`, so that `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` are not replicated. Replication can deal well with lost connectivity (for a while), but it is not an option if you want the data at the source to be deleted after they have been replicated.