# Postgres function logging and raising an exception

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I would like to catch the error raised log some info into a table (`INSERT ErrorLog ...)` related to the error and raise the error back to the caller. I don't want the logged info to be rolled back, how can I accomplish this? We are running Postgres version 8.3

```
DECLARE
  text_var1 text;
  text_var2 text;
  text_var3 text;

INSERT INTO mytab(firstname, lastname) VALUES('Tom', 'Jones');
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytab SET firstname = 'Joe' WHERE lastname = 'Jones';
    x := x + 1;
    y := x / 0;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
 GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                          text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                          text_var3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
    INSERT ErrorLog(message, detail) values(text_var1, text_var2);
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error Occured %\n%', text_var1, text_var2;
    RETURN x;
END;
```

Comment: It's ["Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", never "Postgre"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). And version 8.3 is no typo? That version is ancient.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible the way you display it, because the exception you raise (after trapping the other one) rolls back the transaction an hence also the `INSERT` in the `EXCEPTION` block. The function won't return anything, either, this way.

Ways around this include:

- Raise a `WARNING` instead of the `EXCEPTION`.
- In Postgres 11 or later use a procedure instead of the function, where you can manually control transactions.
- Use dblink or a similar tool to emulate an "autonomous transaction". Example:

  - [How do I do large non-blocking updates in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql/22163648#22163648)