# How to initialise PostgreSQL instance by creating database and tables

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a new database using PostgreSQL and need to
initialise the "database" by creating the database and the
tables.

I was thinking of creating a init.sql file and using the file
together with `Docker` when initialising the docker image.

I need an example which takes care of `initialising`*(creating schemas and tables conditionally based on schema versions)* the database.

I have the following pseudo example and would like to see a real Postgres example.

pseudo example:

1) create database if it does not exist
2) set or increment database design version

// create version 0 tables
3) create tables if it does not exist

// create version 1 tables 
4) create future version tables and apply table alterations

Comment: You might benefit from using a database migration tool such as *Flyway* or *Liquibase* after initialing creating the database. These tools run scripts to define and populate your schema, tables, and data.  These tools can also clear the content of the database for reuse in testing so you need not recreate a new empty database,

Comment: I second Basil's recommendation use a schema migration tool. I am fan of Liquibase but Flyway or e.g. [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) or just as good

Answer (score 2):

CREATE DATABASE can only be executed as a single statement.
So it cannot be run inside a function or DO statement.

[You need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961)

And

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb') THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists'; 
   ELSE
      PERFORM dblink_exec('dbname=' || current_database()  -- current db
                        , 'CREATE DATABASE mydb');
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

[A detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql)

Comment: That script will only work if the login requires no password.

Comment: The script only explains how to create a database, the creation of the schema and the creation of the tables are not detailed in this answer yet. My preferred example would be something that conditionally creates: database, schemas and tables AND caters for schema versioning. This links shows how it is done for mySQL: https://database.guide/how-to-create-a-database-from-a-script-in-mysql/

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't realise it, I was trying to enrich my answer

Comment: @Wayne: that link is useless for Postgres