# Can postgresql stored procedures operate on a separate database?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Can postgresql (specifically 9.6) stored procedures read/modify a separate database, or can they only operate on data within the local database where they are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres 9.6 does not have [***stored procedures***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html), which were introduced with Postgres 11.

You probably mean Postgres [***functions***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), which have been there since time immemorial. It's a widespread misconception to call those "stored procedures".

Both are confined to the database in which they are executed - as Postgres will tell you if you try to prefix a database name to an object name:

> ```
> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented:
> ```

**Unless** you use the [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) infrastructure (you probably want the additional module [***postgres_fdw***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) with that) or [***dblink***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html), which allow exactly that after all ...

- [How to use (install) dblink in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961)
- [Persistent inserts in a UDF even if the function aborts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105186/3684)
- [How do I do large non-blocking updates in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql/22163648#22163648)